# How to set active class to menu item (sessionStorage)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have code like this:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Some <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">Some 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

And JS code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".nav  li a ").click(function () {
    var id = $(this);

    $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");
    $(id).addClass("active");
    sessionStorage .setItem("mylink", $(id).text());
   });

    var mylink = sessionStorage .getItem('mylink');

    if (mylink !== null) {

       $("li:contains('" + mylink + "')").addClass("active");
     }
});
```

I’m trying to achieve that, when I click an on the item in my nav adds “active” class. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The logic to set the class and the sessionStorage value works fine. The issue you have is because when the page loads you put the `active` class on the `li` instead of the `a`. As such the call to `$(".nav li a").removeClass("active")` does nothing. To fix that change this line:

```
$("li:contains('" + mylink + "')").addClass("active");
```

To

```
$("li a:contains('" + mylink + "')").addClass("active");
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/vapnjruy/)

Answer (score 0):

You should add `a` as part of the selector:

Change

```
$("li:contains('" + mylink + "')").addClass("active");
```

To:

```
$("li a:contains('" + mylink + "')").addClass("active");
```

***Demo:***

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var mylink = 'Some 2';
  if (mylink !== null) {
    var el =  $("li a:contains('" + mylink + "')");
    el.addClass("active");
    el.parent().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.active{
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Some <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">Some 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you but now my parent element does not have active class?

Comment: @jomskris, to add class to the parent, you need another line of code.... `$("li a:contains('" + mylink + "')").parent().addClass("active");`

Comment: @jomskris, please see the demo code in the updated answer:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".nav li a").click(function(){
    var id = $(this);
    $(".nav li a").removeClass("active");
    $(id).addClass("active");
    sessionStorage .setItem("mylink", $(id).text());
   }); 
   var mylink = sessionStorage .getItem('mylink');
    if (mylink !== null) {
       $("li a:contains('" + mylink + "')").addClass("active");
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">Some <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">Some 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="">Some 4</a></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="">News</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you but now my parent element does not have active class?